# Make text appear when submit button clicked and checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an agree to terms and agreements. However, when the button is unchecked and the user hits submit, I want it to present the user with an alert telling him to agree to the terms. At first, I made it to where the user couldn't even click on the submit button when the checkbox is unchecked, however, I want the user to be able to click it so he can be alerted with an error. I can't seem to get my code to work no matter what.

```
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('submit');
checker.onchange = function(){
if(this.checked){
    sendbtn.disabled = false;
} else {
    sendbtn.disabled = true;
}
if(document.getElementById('submit').click() & document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;){
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}

}


<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/>
I agree to the terms & service<br />

<input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="md-trigger blue-texture postbit-button-big md-pointer" data-modal="modal-five" id="submit" value=" Send "  onclick="$('.md-modal').removeClass('md-show');" disabled/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want the user to be able to click it so he can be alerted with an error*

- Remove the `disabled` from the submit button.
- Remove the `checker.onchange = function(){`
- Make sure to `event.preventDefault();` browser triggering form submits or other default evett actions

**All you need:**

```
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('submit');

sendbtn.onclick = function( event ){
  event.preventDefault();
  if(!checker.checked){
    alert("You must agree to our terms of service");
  }
};
```

**Note** that you might want to do the above *not* on button *Click* but on ***formID.onsubmit*** (the form can always be submitted even without a *Button* click. Not seeing your form this is all I can suggest.)

**P.S:**
Developer Console (access by F12 and click *Console*) helps to debug such errors like `&/&&` `=/===` missing `;` etc...

---

<sub>P.S<sub>2</sub>: when using only JS a handy function to fast-get an element by ID can be achieved with a nice little function i.e:</sub>

```
function ID(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // ...and use like:
var submitBtn = ID("submit");
```

Comment: The problem with this is that, the button still goes onto the next event. For this instance, I am using a modal and once it's clicked it'll alert me but it still goes on to the next modal.  onclick="$('.md-modal').removeClass('md-show');"

Comment: @RickG. than remove the HTML inline `onclick="$...` and put that jQuery inside the else statement in JS

Comment: I see what you did, that fixed the transition, however, the actual modal is brought up through data-modal="modal-five" which isn't Javascript...

Comment: @RickG. Remove that inline HTML `data` and do some changes in JS: http://jsbin.com/vimira/3/edit

Comment: Took me a while with fiddling with it but I made it work, thanks to your code. The modal-five opening is done through this:  $('#modal-five').addClass('md-show'); but you'd have to know the modal source code to be able to know that.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;` is assigning it to `false`. If you want to check if it is false, you need this

```
document.getElementById("myCheck").checked === false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `disabled` from submit and the other js and use this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    if (!$('#checkme').is(':checked')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Check the box!');
    } else {
        $(e.currentTarget).parent('form').first().submit();
    }
});
```